# Simple category with drupal commerce not showing to anonymous users

Tags: commerce, users

I followed this guide https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/setting-product-catalog and now I have a nice simple category page, but not visible to anonymous users. I tried changing the roles to marking all three options but no luck.. Any suggestions?

[image]
[image]

Comment: check view permissions.

Comment: tried this but no luck... https://www.drupal.org/node/1490434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips:

- Set all checkboxes in People -> Premissions : Product-> View any product of any type
- or If you are using any contextual filter in views configuration be sure that arguement exists in category page;